# find best subset from list of strings to match a given string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, matching, fuzzy-search

I have a string

```
s = "mouse"
```

and a list of string

```
sub_strings = ["m", "o", "se", "e"]
```

I need to find out what is the best and shortest matching subset of sub_strings the list that matches s.
What is the best way to do this?
The ideal result would be ["m", "o", "se"] since together they spell mose

Comment: The right answer here might depend on how the length of the string compares to the number of substrings. How long will the string be in practice? How many substrings will you have? Does it need to be super fast?

Comment: What do you mean by "best and shortest"?

Comment: The string can be as big as possible and the sub-strings will be also pretty big but all sub-strings must be part of the string.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12377231/68063) and its answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re

def matches(s, sub_strings):
    sub_strings = sorted(sub_strings, key=len, reverse=True)
    pattern = '|'.join(re.escape(substr) for substr in sub_strings)
    return re.findall(pattern, s)
```

This is at least short and quick, but it will not necessarily find the best set of matches; it is too greedy. For example,

```
matches("bears", ["bea", "be", "ars"])
```

returns `["bea"]`, when it should return `["be", "ars"]`.

---

Explanation of the code:

- The first line sorts the substrings by length, so that the longest strings appear at the start of the list. This makes sure that the regular expression will prefer longer matches over shorter ones.
- The second line creates a regular expression pattern consisting of all the substrings, separated by the `|` symbol, which means “or”.
- The third line just uses the `re.findall` function to find all matches of the pattern in the given string `s`.

Comment: I thought of a possible reason to -1 it, so I edited the answer a little.

Comment: I did not -1 anything sorry. This is the perfect answer guys. thanks

Comment: −1 because it doesn't solve the OP's problem. You say so yourself in the answer: "it is too greedy".

Comment: Thanks, Gareth. Can't argue with that.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12379137/68063) by user [Running Wild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1296466/running-wild). It uses [the `acora` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/acora/) by Stefan Behnel to efficiently find all the matches of the substrings in the target using the [Aho–Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) and then uses [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to find the answer.

```
import acora
import collections

def best_match(target, substrings):
    """
    Find the best way to cover the string `target` by non-overlapping
    matches with strings taken from `substrings`. Return the best
    match as a list of substrings in order. (The best match is one
    that covers the largest number of characters in `target`, and
    among all such matches, the one using the fewest substrings.)

    >>> best_match('mouse', ['mo', 'ou', 'us', 'se'])
    ['mo', 'us']
    >>> best_match('aaaaaaa', ['aa', 'aaa'])
    ['aaa', 'aa', 'aa']
    >>> best_match('abracadabra', ['bra', 'cad', 'dab'])
    ['bra', 'cad', 'bra']
    """
    # Find all occurrences of the substrings in target and store them
    # in a dictionary by their position.
    ac = acora.AcoraBuilder(*substrings).build()
    matches = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for match, pos in ac.finditer(target):
        matches[pos].add(match)

    n = len(target)
    # Array giving the best (score, list of matches) found so far, for
    # each initial substring of the target.
    best = [(0, []) for _ in xrange(n + 1)]
    for i in xrange(n):
        bi = best[i]
        bj = best[i + 1]
        if bi[0] > bj[0] or bi[0] == bj[0] and len(bi[1]) < bj[1]:
            best[i + 1] = bi
        for m in matches[i]:
            j = i + len(m)
            bj = best[j]
            score = bi[0] + len(m)
            if score > bj[0] or score == bj[0] and len(bi[1]) < len(bj[1]):
                best[j] = (score, bi[1] + [m])
    return best[n][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import difflib
print difflib.get_close_matches(target_word,list_of_possibles)
```

but unfortunately it would not work for your example above
you can use Levenstein distance instead...

```
def levenshtein_distance(first, second):
    """Find the Levenshtein distance between two strings."""
    if len(first) > len(second):
        first, second = second, first
    if len(second) == 0:
        return len(first)
    first_length = len(first) + 1
    second_length = len(second) + 1
    distance_matrix = [[0] * second_length for x in range(first_length)]
    for i in range(first_length):
       distance_matrix[i][0] = i
    for j in range(second_length):
       distance_matrix[0][j]=j
    for i in xrange(1, first_length):
        for j in range(1, second_length):
            deletion = distance_matrix[i-1][j] + 1
            insertion = distance_matrix[i][j-1] + 1
            substitution = distance_matrix[i-1][j-1]
            if first[i-1] != second[j-1]:
                substitution += 1
            distance_matrix[i][j] = min(insertion, deletion, substitution)
    return distance_matrix[first_length-1][second_length-1]

sub_strings = ["mo", "m,", "o", "se", "e"]
s="mouse"
print sorted(sub_strings,key = lambda x:levenshtein_distance(x,s))[0]
```

this will always give you the "closest" word to your target(for some definition of closest)

levenshtein function stolen from :http://www.korokithakis.net/posts/finding-the-levenshtein-distance-in-python/

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort. This is a good start. I might have not described it properly but lets use another example. Lets assume the substring is just sub_strings = ["m", "o", "se", "e"] then i expect the combination ["m", "o", "se"] to be the result since together they spell mose which is the nearest combination to mouse! I will update my example

Comment: then se should be the closest ... oh i see what your doing ... no idea ... start with this and work from there you will probably need `itertools.combinations` (or maybe permutations ... I often confuse the two)...and it will probably be slow ... very slow ...

Comment: −1 because it does not solve the OP's problem. The code in the answer prints `"mo"`, which is wrong.